# FormData as payload to vuex action

Tags: vuex, multipartform-data

I need help. There is anyway to send FormData as payload for Vuex Action?

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      sendMessage: 'modules/modal/send_message'
    }),
    Send() {
      this.End = !this.End
      this.AutoClose()
      this.msg.append('name', this.Name)
      this.msg.append('phone', this.Phone)
      console.log(this.msg)
      this.sendMessage(this.msg)
    },
```

And in Actions

```
const actions = {
  send_message(payload) {
    Axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/content/create?type=Emails',
      data: payload,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But server responding:

> [Create] error: no multipart boundary param in Content-Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty `{}` as first argument to your action and it should work.

```
const actions = {
   send_message({}, payload) {
      ...
```

> Action handlers receive a context object which exposes the same set of methods/properties on the store instance, so you can call context.commit to commit a mutation, or access the state and getters via context.state and context.getters.

[Reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)